# java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIdent while updating mapbox dependencies using jdk-17

Tags: android, java-8, android-gradle-plugin, mapbox-android

**Environment**

Android OS version:31

JDK: jdk-17

AGP: 8.0

Gradle: 8.0.2

---

**Observed behavior and steps to reproduce:**

I'm using jdk-17 because of gradle 8 update and I'm trying to upgrade the mapbox dependencies

here is the gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-parcelize'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
apply plugin: 'androidx.navigation.safeargs'
apply plugin: 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'

def getGitHash = { ->
    def stdout = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
    exec {
        commandLine 'git', 'rev-parse', '--short', 'HEAD'
        standardOutput = stdout
    }
    return stdout.toString().trim()
}

def getSourceBranch(Boolean prod) {
    def process = "git symbolic-ref --short -q HEAD".execute()
    def branch = process.text.trim()
    if (prod) {
        if (branch != "master") {
            println("WARNING: PRODUCTION BUILD NOT BEING BUILT OFF OF MASTER")
        }
        branch = ""
    }
    println 'getSourceBranch: ' + branch
    return "\"" + branch + "\""
}

def computeVersionCode() {
    return 12
}

def setupSigningConfig(String flavor) {
    println 'setupKeystore: Setting up keystore info for flavor: ' + flavor
    def filename = (flavor == "release" ? 'production' : 'development')

    def keystoreFile = 'keystore/' + filename + '.jks'
    android.signingConfigs[flavor].storeFile = file(keystoreFile)

    def propsFile = rootProject.file('NomNomStock/keystore/' + filename + '.properties')

    def storePassword, keyAlias, keyPassword
    if (propsFile.exists()) {
        println 'setupKeystore: Propsfile = ' + propsFile + ' exists!'
        def props = new Properties()
        props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile))

        storePassword = props['storePassword']
        keyAlias = props['keyAlias']
        keyPassword = props['keyPassword']
    } else {
        println 'setupKeystore: Using enviornment variables'
        storePassword = System.getenv("KEYSTORE_PASS")
        keyAlias = System.getenv("ALIAS_NAME")
        keyPassword = System.getenv("ALIAS_PASS")
    }
    android.signingConfigs[flavor].storePassword = storePassword
    android.signingConfigs[flavor].keyAlias = keyAlias
    android.signingConfigs[flavor].keyPassword = keyPassword
}

def getVersionNameFromPropsFile() {
    // buildVersionName defined in [gradle.properties] file
    // it is done so to simplify access to buildVersionName from fastlane
    println("Build string: " + buildVersionName)
    return buildVersionName
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {

        applicationId "com.abc.efg"

        minSdkVersion rootProject.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.targetSdkVersion

        versionCode computeVersionCode()
        versionName getVersionNameFromPropsFile()

        multiDexEnabled true
        setProperty("archivesBaseName", applicationName + "-" + versionName + "(" + versionCode + ")")

        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'

        buildConfigField "String", "GIT_SHA", "\"${gitSha}\""
    }

    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file("keystore/development.jks")
        }
        release {
            storeFile file("keystore/production.jks")
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        development {
            applicationId "com.abc.efg.development"
            versionName getVersionNameFromPropsFile()
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_BRANCH", getSourceBranch(false)
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_PRODUCTION", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "RESTRICT_MAP_SEARCH", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DisableForceOrderingAhead", "false"
            buildConfigField "String", "GitHash", "\"${getGitHash()}\""
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED", "true"
            setupSigningConfig "debug"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        staging {
            applicationId "com.abc.efg.staging"
            versionName getVersionNameFromPropsFile()
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_BRANCH", getSourceBranch(false)
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_PRODUCTION", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "RESTRICT_MAP_SEARCH", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DisableForceOrderingAhead", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED", "true"
            buildConfigField "String", "GitHash", "\"${getGitHash()}\""
            setupSigningConfig "debug"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        preProduction {
            applicationId "com.abc.efg.preproduction"
            versionName getVersionNameFromPropsFile()
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_BRANCH", getSourceBranch(true)
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_PRODUCTION", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "RESTRICT_MAP_SEARCH", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DisableForceOrderingAhead", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED", "true"
            buildConfigField "String", "GitHash", "\"${getGitHash()}\""
            setupSigningConfig "release"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        production {
            applicationId "com.abc.efg"
            versionName getVersionNameFromPropsFile()
            buildConfigField "String", "BUILD_BRANCH", getSourceBranch(true)
            buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_PRODUCTION", "true"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "RESTRICT_MAP_SEARCH", "false"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "DisableForceOrderingAhead", "true"
            buildConfigField "boolean", "PUSH_NOTIFICATIONS_ENABLED", "true"
            buildConfigField "String", "GitHash", "\"${getGitHash()}\""
            setupSigningConfig "release"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }

        flavorDimensions "default"
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            println("**** buildType: debug")
            minifyEnabled false
            debuggable true
        }

        release {
            println("**** buildType: release")
            zipAlignEnabled true
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules-release.pro'
            debuggable false
        }
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
        dataBinding true
    }
    dexOptions {
        jumboMode = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    }
    kotlinOptions {
       jvmTarget = '17'
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += ['META-INF/atomicfu.kotlin_module']
        }
    }
    namespace 'com.abc.efg.stock'
    lint {
        abortOnError true
        baseline file('lint-baseline.xml')
    }
    kapt {
        correctErrorTypes true
    }

}

realm {
    kotlinExtensionsEnabled = false
}


dependencies {
    //implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')

    implementation project(':libs:appUserStorage')
    implementation project(':libs:apiNomNom')
    implementation project(':libs:commonAndroid')
    implementation project(':libs:featureAuthentication')
    implementation project(':libs:featureProfile')
    implementation project(':libs:featureDeliveryAddressSelectionFragment')
    implementation project(':libs:featurePaymentMethods')
    implementation project(':libs:featureLocationAutocomplete')
    implementation project(':libs:featureLocationSearch')
    implementation project(':libs:featureAppReviewDialog')
    implementation project(':libs:featureTooltips')
    implementation project(':libs:featureAppLoyalty')
    implementation project(':libs:featureRecentOrdersCache')

    implementation project(':appCore')
    implementation project(':toolkit')
    implementation project(':sdkRadius')

    implementation platform("com.radiusnetworks.flybuy:bom:2.5.3")
    implementation 'com.radiusnetworks.flybuy:presence'
    implementation 'com.radiusnetworks.flybuy:notify'

    // Android Support Libraries
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:$rootProject.androidXCore"
    implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:$rootProject.appCompatVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.androidDesignMaterialVersion"
    implementation "androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:$rootProject.recyclerViewVersion"
    implementation "androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:$rootProject.constraintLayoutVersion"

    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

    // Google Services Libraries
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$rootProject.firebaseMessaging"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:21.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:21.3.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:$firebaseCrashlytics"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:18.0.3"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:18.0.3'


    // Mapbox
    implementation 'com.mapbox.maps:android:10.15.0-beta.1'
    implementation "com.mapbox.search:mapbox-search-android:1.0.0-rc.6"
    implementation "com.mapbox.search:mapbox-search-android-ui:1.0.0-rc.6"
    implementation "com.mapbox.search:offline:1.0.0-rc.6"
    implementation "com.mapbox.search:place-autocomplete:1.0.0-rc.6"
    implementation "com.mapbox.search:discover:1.0.0-rc.6"
    implementation "com.mapbox.search:autofill:1.0.0-rc.6"
    implementation "com.mapbox.navigation:android:2.14.0"
    //TODO comment the old mapbox dependencies and uncomment the above one.
    /*implementation files('libs/mapbox-android-plugin-annotation-v9-0.9.0.aar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-android-plugin-places-v9-0.12.0.aar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-android-sdk-9.2.1.aar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-sdk-services-5.8.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-java-geojson-2.2.10.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-sdk-geojson-5.8.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-sdk-core-5.8.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-sdk-turf-5.7.0.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-sdk-directions-refresh-models-5.9.0-alpha.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-sdk-directions-models-5.9.0-alpha.1.jar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-android-core-4.0.0.aar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-android-gestures-0.7.0.aar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-android-telemetry-7.0.0.aar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-android-accounts-0.8.0.aar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-android-plugin-localization-0.6.0.aar')
    implementation files('libs/mapbox-android-geocoder-1.0.0.aar')*/

    implementation "androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.2.0"

    // App related dependencies.
    implementation('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:5.2.7@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
//    implementation "ua.at.tsvetkov:taolog:$rootProject.taologVersion"

    // Kotlin
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:$googleNavigationVersion"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:$googleNavigationVersion"

    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.3.0'
    implementation 'com.instabug.library:instabug:10.13.0'
    implementation "com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:4.3.0"
    implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.1'

    implementation "com.stripe:stripe-android:$rootProject.stripeVersion"
    implementation 'org.jcodec:jcodec-android:0.1.9'
    implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.13'
    kapt  'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.13'
//    debugImplementation 'com.squareup.leakcanary:leakcanary-android:2.9.1'
    testImplementation "junit:junit:$rootProject.junitVersion"

    implementation project(':libs:libAndroidCommon')
    implementation project(':libs:libAndroidLocation')
    implementation project(':libs:libAndroidViewPagerIndicator')
    implementation project(':libs:libAndroidMaterialEditText')
    implementation project(':libs:NomNomCoreSDK')
    implementation project(':libs:libCoreApiRx')
    implementation project(':libs:sdkSample')
    implementation project(':libs:sdkOlo')
    implementation project(':libs:libCommon')
    implementation project(':libs:sdkPunchh')
    implementation project(':libs:libAuthFacebook')

    implementation "io.reactivex:rxjava:$rootProject.rxJavaVersion"
    implementation "io.reactivex:rxandroid:$rootProject.rxAndroidVersion"

    implementation "com.airbnb.android:lottie:$rootProject.rxLottieVersion"

    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-work:$rootProject.hiltAndroidXVersion"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-fragment:$rootProject.hiltAndroidXVersion"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:$rootProject.hiltAndroidXVersion"

    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:$rootProject.hiltVersion"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:$rootProject.hiltVersion"

    implementation "com.tbuonomo:dotsindicator:$rootProject.dotsIndicatorVersion"

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:$rootProject.coroutinesVersion"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:$rootProject.coroutinesVersion"

    implementation 'androidx.viewpager:viewpager:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.viewpager2:viewpager2:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$lifecycle_extensions"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    testImplementation "androidx.test.ext:junit:$rootProject.androidXjunitExtVersion"
    testImplementation "androidx.test:core:$rootProject.androidXTestCoreVersion"
    testImplementation "org.robolectric:robolectric:$rootProject.robolectricVersion"
    testImplementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$rootProject.okHttpVersion"
    testImplementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:$rootProject.daggerVersion"
    kaptTest "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$rootProject.daggerVersion"

    //coreLibraryDesugaring "com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:$rootProject.desugarLibraryVersion"

    implementation 'com.guolindev.permissionx:permissionx:1.7.1'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-metadata-jvm:0.6.2"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
```

But I'm getting this error at compile time:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIdent cannot be cast to class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCArrayTypeTree (com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIdent and com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCArrayTypeTree are in module jdk.compiler of loader 'app')
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.visitVarDef(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.PrettyWithWorkarounds.visitVarDef(Kapt3Extension.kt:398)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCVariableDecl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printExpr(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printExpr(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printExprs(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printExprs(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.visitMethodDef(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCMethodDecl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printExpr(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printStat(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printStats(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printBlock(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.visitClassDef(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCClassDecl.accept(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printExpr(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printStat(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printUnit(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.visitTopLevel(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCCompilationUnit.accept(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printExpr(Unknown Source)
    at jdk.compiler/com.sun.tools.javac.tree.Pretty.printStat(Unknown Source)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.Kapt3ExtensionKt.prettyPrint(Kapt3Extension.kt:373)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.saveStubs(Kapt3Extension.kt:347)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.generateKotlinSourceStubs(Kapt3Extension.kt:308)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.AbstractKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:175)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.kapt3.ClasspathBasedKapt3Extension.analysisCompleted(Kapt3Extension.kt:104)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM$analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$2.invoke(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:125)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:257)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:248)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:495)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.runCompiler(IncrementalJvmCompilerRunner.kt:133)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.doCompile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:486)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileImpl(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:409)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compileNonIncrementally(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:290)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.incremental.IncrementalCompilerRunner.compile(IncrementalCompilerRunner.kt:112)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:627)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImplBase.access$execIncrementalCompiler(CompileServiceImpl.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1587)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

Errors were stored into /Users/Ali/StudioProjects/android-native/.gradle/kotlin/errors/errors-1688562997837.log
```

If i use old mapbox dependencies the project is compiled successfully (but it has other problem explained below).
If i use new dependencies i get the error i mentioned. i tried changing the jdk version to 18 and 19. but it doesn't work. i also tried to change it to 1.8 and 11. but i get issues since i'm using gradle 8.0.2.

If i don't update the dependency i get this error below in android S+ and above:

```
Error occurred while initializing telemetry
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.abc.efg.development: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent. Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:382)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcastAsUser(PendingIntent.java:673)
at android.app.PendingIntent.getBroadcast(PendingIntent.java:660)
at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.AlarmSchedulerFlusher.register(AlarmSchedulerFlusher.java:31)
at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.MapboxTelemetry.startAlarm(MapboxTelemetry.java:380)
at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.MapboxTelemetry.startTelemetry(MapboxTelemetry.java:374)
at com.mapbox.android.telemetry.MapboxTelemetry.enable(MapboxTelemetry.java:114)
at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.module.telemetry.TelemetryImpl.<init>(TelemetryImpl.java:33)
at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.ModuleProviderImpl.obtainTelemetry(ModuleProviderImpl.java:22)
at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.initializeTelemetry(Mapbox.java:167)
at com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.Mapbox.getInstance(Mapbox.java:64)
at com.abc.efg.stock.views.map.AppMapFragment.onCreate(AppMapFragment.kt:91)
at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:3094)
...............
```

Comment: Happened to me too. Different versions of everything but the same error. The advice below does not help. Did you solve this problem? How?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this happened after moving many packages to another package. The IDE did not correctly handle `import` statement in classes after they had been moved.
Use in Android Studio `Main menu` => `Code` => `Inspect Code..` for search broken code.

Comment: This was the issue for me, I found the easiest fix was to search for the names of classes that were moved, then you will need to update the `import` packages

Answer (score 0):

Most likely this is a dependency missing. Execute your build with `--debug` and search for the exception message `"class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCIdent cannot be cast to class com.sun.tools.javac.tree.JCTree$JCArrayTypeTree"`. Kapt should print right before this line what source file it tried to compile last; this is the place to look at.